# Search Engine Index Javascript Tabs

Tags: javascript, seo, tabs

I have a website that is 1 html file and uses javascript to hide tabbed pages.

The url gets rewritten with a # for the different pages to make them bookmark-able.

Is there a way to make the different pages show in search engine results? It would be good to have them show up as different pages there.

I have read the below doc, but I think that is just for dynamically generated ajax content, right?

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the page mentioned by you. That is for Ajax site. In your case it is not Ajax.
Another point as Jeff B has mentioned is that the chance is high that Google will index all content for each trick you use. In that case it would be bad as Google will get duplicate content. It will be not very bad as all content are from your site only.

Search Engine questions like this are very tricky and difficult to answer as no one know the exact functioning of Search Engine.

1. In my thinking you either recreate your pages as Ajax and follow the points mentioned in article you got. Or
2. Use a link for each tag with param. like page1.php?cat1, page1.php?cat2, etc.
   and that only load content related to specific tag at a time.

The second solution is no different than implementing different page for each tab, but it can be easier to update in your case! and also all content are still accessible by both person and search engine at a place. Slowly search engine will index your each page with parameter. Remember, It is generally said that Google does not index pages with parameter but it is not true. Google does not index page with variable or id kind of parameter only. They index each page with popular parameters if page content changes.

Still your question is tricky and my suggestion is what comes to me after thinking much about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that even if the different pages were indexed, they would all index the same content.  This is because according to your explanation all of the content (including hidden) exists at load time.

If your tabs are links, you simply need to put the href in the link.  Google should follow this link, while javascript-enabled browsers will execute your tab-switching code and not follow the link (if you coded it right).

However, the problem of all content being indexed for all pages still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your system like this:

1. Every link that changes the content of the current tab should have
   as href attribute a subpage that contains the content of the tab
   intended to appear -> this will be cached by Search Engines.
2. Those links should have binded JS actions that changes the content
   of the current tab and also denies the redirecting that should have
   been done by what's in the "href" attribute -> this will be shown to
   the user